# Building angular application, getting all the images used in application, font files in dist folder instead of regular assets folder? Why?

Tags: angular

I created an angular 6 application. It's directory structure is regular like project/src/assets. After building the project, in dist folder, there are many compiled files like images which are specifically used in background & also font files. How to avoid this garbage?

this is some part of the code from angular.json file.

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/projectabc",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/sass/main.scss",
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "src/assets/js/jquery-ui.js",
              "src/assets/js/custom.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "projectabc:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "projectabc:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "projectabc:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/sass/main.scss",
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/server/icicipru",
            "main": "src/main.server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The dist directory represents the fully compiled project with all assets included.  You shouldnt copy anything but that into a production environment, which is why all assets are there.

Comment: Not all assets. Only the fonts and images which are called through css in background are over there. Also they are in assets folder created in same dist folder. Can't we have structure like dist/index.html, dist/assets/js, dist/assets/images/, dist/assets/fonts?

Comment: You can.. you can edit the <base href> location in your index.html and move the files to whatever sub-directory... but the `/dist` directory is your applications root.  so your original issue with the assets being moved there doesnt change that they should be there

Comment: I'm not worried about assets are compiled into dist folder. i want them into subfolders inside dist folder and the index.html in dist root.